# NextJs image shows an empty container with the same dimensions above it, leaving a large gap on the page

Tags: reactjs, image, next.js, safari

So when the page loads, two spots will appear for the image, the first empty and the second with image.

I found that `layout="intrinsic"` prevents this behavior for most browsers, but not for Safari.

Can someone explain to me what is going on here and how I can properly solve this problem? I also have my doubts about this `layout="intrinsic"` fix.

Thanks in advance!